# flink cdc java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ververica.cdc.debezium.DebeziumDeserializationSchema.deserialize

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Run with flink mysql cdc, it raised :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ververica.cdc.debezium.DebeziumDeserializationSchema.deserialize(Lorg/apache/kafka/connect/source/SourceRecord;Lorg/apache/flink/util/Collector;)V
    at com.ververica.cdc.connectors.mysql.source.reader.MySqlRecordEmitter.emitElement(MySqlRecordEmitter.java:129)
    at com.ververica.cdc.connectors.mysql.source.reader.MySqlRecordEmitter.processElement(MySqlRecordEmitter.java:111)
    at com.ververica.cdc.connectors.mysql.source.reader.MySqlRecordEmitter.emitRecord(MySqlRecordEmitter.java:83)
    at com.ververica.cdc.connectors.mysql.source.reader.MySqlRecordEmitter.emitRecord(MySqlRecordEmitter.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.SourceReaderBase.pollNext(SourceReaderBase.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SourceOperator.emitNext(SourceOperator.java:305)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskSourceInput.emitNext(StreamTaskSourceInput.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:423)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:204)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:684)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeInvoke(StreamTask.java:639)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:650)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:623)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:779)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:566)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

my pom dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner-blink_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ververica</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-mysql-cdc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ververica</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-sql-connector-mysql-cdc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ververica</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-debezium</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and my java code:

```
import com.ververica.cdc.connectors.mysql.source.MySqlSource;
import com.ververica.cdc.debezium.JsonDebeziumDeserializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

public class MysqlCDC {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MySqlSource<String> source = MySqlSource.<String>builder()
                .hostname("xxx")
                .port(3306)
                .databaseList("mydb")
                .tableList("mydb.testcdc")
                .username("xxx")
                .password("xxx")
                .deserializer(new JsonDebeziumDeserializationSchema()).build();

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.enableCheckpointing(6000);
        env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "mysql source")
                .setParallelism(1)
                .print("输出数据==>");
        env.execute();
    }
}
```